Magento 2: Connect a live chat in magento 2 with ChatGPT
I want to connect a livechat on magento 2 with ChatGPT and enable chatgpt to read all the data on the website and use it to answer visitor's queries.
Is there a way to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

well for that i suspect you will have to create a paid account in chat gpt first cause the api won't allow you to send that much amount of data for free i guess. May be some module exist regardless of integration but if not it's like any other api call.
